# Deriving values from loop operation

Tags: math, loops, set

This is language agnostic, but I am interested in the successful answer's problem solving process. I have the following three columns:

```
3   0   1
3   1   2
3   2   3

2   0   2
2   1   3

1   0   3
```

What common operation will always derive the third column from the first two columns? If it helps this question is derived from a loop. I have data that needs to be grouped in sets of 4, if a set has four, no need to fill it out. if the set has less than 4, the first column, I need to loop through, iteration in column 2, and fill the set out assigning col#s, column 3, to the class of the items. Again, more interested in process than just the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a pattern recognition question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the answer is `4 - a + b`:

```
a  b  4-a+b
_  _  _
3  0  1
3  1  2
3  2  3
2  0  2
2  1  3
1  0  3
```

In any language that supports two-dimensional arrays, you do not need to go through the thinking and figuring out the math: it's not worth being fancy where a simple lookup table would do the job:

```
int[][] lookup = new int[][] {
    new int[0]
,   new int[] { 3 }
,   new int[] { 2, 3 }
,   new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

Comment: I realize this turned out to be ridiculously simple, but I'll try your method on more complex problems.

Answer (score 1):

Writing it out helped, as usual I guess. Turns out it was:

```
col3 = 4-(col1-col2)
```